# addForeignKeyConstraint + liquibase using in maven pom

Tags: mysql, pom.xml, liquibase

I need to create below tables using liquibase but getting below error. Can someone help me to identify what is wrong in this? I am new to DB & liquibase.

```
<changeSet author="mohan" id="table-for-users-roles">
    <createTable tableName="USERS">
        <column name="ID" type="NUMBER(19,0)" >
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_USERS"/>
        </column>
        <column name="NAME" type="VARCHAR2(10)" remarks="User name"></column>
        <column name="PASSWORD" type="VARCHAR2(10)" remarks="Password"></column>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="ROLES">
        <column name="ID" type="NUMBER(19,0)" >
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_ROLES"/>
        </column>
        <column name="NAME" type="VARCHAR2(10)" remarks="Role name"></column>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="USER_ROLES">
        <column name="USER_ID" type="NUMBER(19,0)" >
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_USER_ROLES"/>
        </column>
        <column name="ROLE_ID" type="NUMBER(19,0)">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_USER_ROLES"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="FK_USERS" baseColumnNames="ID" baseTableName="USERS" referencedTableName="USER_ROLES" referencedColumnNames="USER_ID" />

    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="FK_ROLES" baseColumnNames="ID" baseTableName="ROLES" referencedTableName="USER_ROLES" referencedColumnNames="ROLE_ID" />   
</changeSet>
```

Here is the error:

```
SEVERE 2/10/16 10:32 AM: liquibase: change-logs/wm-db-changelog-master.xml: change-logs/1.0/wm-db-changelog-1.0.xml::table-for-users-roles::mohan: Change Set change-logs/1.0/wm-db-changelog-1.0.xml::table-for-users-roles::mohan failed.  Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
[Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USERS FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES USER_ROLES (USER_ID)] liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
[Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USERS FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES USER_ROLES (USER_ID)]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:301)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run liquibase with `updateSQL` instead of just `update`. Then liquibase will not run SQLs it generated directly on the db but write the SQLs into a file. Then you can take alle the SQLs and run them on command line or using any DB tool. Then you can find which of the generated SQLs produces the error. If they are all ok, then maybe liquibase does not run the SQLs in the right order. Then you should divide them up into multiple changesets (which might be a good idea anyways). If the SQLs do not work then it's not a liquibase problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running all these changes in a single changeset, separate them into at least two changesets. Specifically, I would separate the changes relating the USERS and ROLES tables to each other in a second changeset.